# How Can I Configure My DNS Settings?

Tags: 16.04, networking, gnome, dns

I live in Turkey where Imgur, Pastebin etc are banned and are not accessible on default wifi settings.

By using Google DNS I can reach these sites but I am running into some issues right now

[image: IPV4 Settings]

[image: DNS]

I need to remove my router's default gateway AKA 192.168.2.1 but I don't know how.

I need to disable it in order to access imgur and such.

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Please assist me.

Comment: Maybe turn off the "Automatic" switch to the right of "DNS"?

Comment: @muru 192 still remains and the inaccessible sites remain inaccessible. Do I have to restart for it to take effect?